# How to get the difference between two timestamps in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp

I have a dataframe :

```
+----------------+---------------
time             |  time_dest
------------------------------------
|17/02/2020 00:06|17/02/2020 00:16|               
|17/02/2020 00:16|17/02/2020 00:26|               
|17/02/2020 00:26|17/02/2020 00:36|              
|17/02/2020 00:36|17/02/2020 00:46|              
|17/02/2020 00:46|17/02/2020 00:56|
```

I want to add a column "duration on second" and calculate the duration between time and time_dest, taking into account that time and time_dest are of type string.

I tried that but doesn't work :

```
 DF_F.withColumn(col("Duration", (col("time_dest")-col("time"))))
```

How can I do that ?

thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`to_timestamp,cast(LongType)`** then subtract **`time_dest,time`** columns to get the difference!

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("Duration",to_timestamp(col("time_dest"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").cast(LongType)-
to_timestamp(col("time"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").cast(LongType)).show()

//or by using unix_timestamp function

df.withColumn("Duration",unix_timestamp(col("time_dest"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").cast(LongType)-unix_timestamp(col("time"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").cast(LongType)).show()

//+----------------+----------------+--------+
//|            time|       time_dest|Duration|
//+----------------+----------------+--------+
//|17/02/2020 00:06|17/02/2020 00:16|     600|
//|17/02/2020 00:16|17/02/2020 00:26|     600|
//+----------------+----------------+--------+
```

---

If you need duration in `minutes,hours` then:

```
df.withColumn("Duration",to_timestamp(col("time_dest"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").cast(LongType)-to_timestamp(col("time"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").cast(LongType)).
withColumn("Duration_mins",round(col("Duration")/60)).
withColumn("Duration_hours",round(col("Duration")/3600)).
show()

//+----------------+----------------+--------+-------------+--------------+
//|            time|       time_dest|Duration|Duration_mins|Duration_hours|
//+----------------+----------------+--------+-------------+--------------+
//|17/02/2020 00:06|17/02/2020 00:16|     600|         10.0|           0.0|
//|17/02/2020 00:16|17/02/2020 00:26|     600|         10.0|           0.0|
//+----------------+----------------+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but he doesn't accept the function " to_timestamp"; any idea!

Comment: @HajarBOUALAMIA, which version of spark are u using?

Comment: I"m using version 3.0.0-preview2

Comment: @HajarBOUALAMIA, `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` try to import functions and also i added using `unix_timestamp` function also, try with these two approaches once!